# Calling Java from Node.js

Tags: javascript, java, node.js, npm, reflection

I'm trying to follow this simple [tutorial about calling Java from Node.js](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-run-java-code-in-node-js/):

My test script:

```
var java = require('java');
var javaLangSystem = java.import('java.lang.System');

javaLangSystem.out.printlnSync('Hello Java!');
```

Here is the console:

```
$ npm init
This utility will walk you through creating a package.json file.
It only covers the most common items, and tries to guess sensible defaults.
...
$ npm install java

added 18 packages, and audited 19 packages in 11s

1 package is looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

2 high severity vulnerabilities

To address all issues, run:
  npm audit fix

Run `npm audit` for details.
$ node test.js 
/home/Projects/test-java/node_modules/java/lib/nodeJavaBridge.js:240
  var fields = SyncCall(clazz, 'getDeclaredFields')();
                                                   ^

Error: Error running instance method
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.base/java.util.Objects.requireNonNull(Objects.java:208)
    at java.base/java.lang.invoke.MethodHandleImpl$1.reflectiveInvoker(MethodHandleImpl.java:1660)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:131)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:577)

    at Java.java.import (/home/Projects/test-java/node_modules/java/lib/nodeJavaBridge.js:240:52)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/Projects/test-java/test.js:2:33)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1103:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1157:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
  cause: nodeJava_java_lang_NullPointerException {}
}
$ java --version
java 18.0.1 2022-04-19
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 18.0.1+10-24)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 18.0.1+10-24, mixed mode, sharing)
```

**What may be going wrong here?**

I've tried to debug it and it seems that `obj[syncMethodName].bind(obj)()` throws a `java.lang.NullPointerException` at `java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:577)` when

```
obj == class java.lang.System
syncMethodName == 'getDeclaredFieldsSync'
```

Comment: Ouch. Java 18 changed how `@CallerSensitive` methods behave when called without a java stack frame. `System.out` in js will call `getDeclaredMethods` on the `System.class`.

Comment: Are you suggesting replacing 'getDeclaredFields' with 'getDeclaredMethods'?

Comment: Ohh, sorry, misstyped. should be `getDeclaredFields`, but in the end, both methods are caller sensitive.

Comment: Are you suggesting any practical solution based on your observation?

Comment: No, not at all. It's just that that npm's java package doesn't work with Java 18, because of some changes in Java. It's a bug, either in that package, or a regression in Java 18, depending on how you look at it.

Comment: Many things may change in every new version of Java. You have to know what parts of Java were used in the external library in order to be able to identify those specific parts of Java that have changed in the new version and are now causing the miscommunication between the two systems. But you seem to say that you have no clear idea of the former.

Comment: I have no idea about nodejs. Java 18 changed the way reflection works, and `@CallerSensitive` methods, such as `getDeclaredFields`, can behave strangely when called through reflection with no underlying Java frame.